# How to import Bootstrap variables into SASS module?

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js, bootstrap-5, css-modules

is there a way to use Bootstrap SASS variables in SASS module?

For example I have file index.module.scss inside my react/NextJS project. How can I use in that sass module variable from bootstrap? Something like this:

```
.hero{
    color: $blue-200;
}
```

If i just add this import at start of file:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I got this error (from NextJS):
[image]

Let me notice, that when I use this import in non-module sass file (lets say in file index.scss), then it works. But I need (want) to use SASS modules...

Any idea how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh, I find a solution. I can add this three imports (instead that one bootstrap imports):

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

These three imports together works and doesn't cause error...

Comment: But with theme customization it seems to not work... (Using NextJS).